# Monitoring windows processes

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, process, hook, monitor

I'd like get a notification if a particular process starts. For ex., if xyz.exe starts in the background, I need a messagebox stating the same.

I'm a little familiar with Windows Hooks in VC++. Can someone point me to some similar links or methods to achieve my goal? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check answers for this question: [How to monitor process/program execution in windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510372/how-to-monitor-process-program-execution-in-windows)

Answer (score 0):

It's a Win32 FAQ (see the [Win32 api group](http://news://nntp.aioe.org/comp.os.ms-windows.programmer.win32) for official method (Microsoft))