# C# Determine when an external app is run or exited

Tags: c#, detect

What's the best way, from a long-running process, to detect when the first instance of an arbitrary application (e.g. MS Word) is launched, and when the last instance of it is closed? (Actual process terminated, not just being hidden to taskbar etc)

Comment: Possible duplicate for [How to monitor process/program execution in windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/510372/791745) or [C# Process Monitor](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1986249/791745)