# Is there a method in the Windows API for firing off code when a specific application is run?

Tags: windows, winapi

I want to monitor the status of an application that runs in Windows. What is the best method (Win32 or newer API) that I can use to watch for when a specific application is run and execute another app of my choice thereafter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the WMI - see this SO question and answer [How to monitor process/program execution in windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510372/how-to-monitor-process-program-execution-in-windows).

Specifically the  [Win32_ProcessStartTrace class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-nz/library/windows/desktop/aa394374(v=vs.85).aspx)

There are some other options in that thread also.